# Auto enable embed youtube video with get_post() function

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, embed

I use get_post() function to get a specific post content. However, I cannot make the auto embed video runs.

Here is the code

```
<?php
$post_id = 110;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
$content = $queried_post->post_content;
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
$content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

I want it auto detect the youtube link and enable the embed video.
The sample content is

```
Check out this cool video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nTDNLUzjkpg

That was a cool video.
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post

http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but this is what I can tell you:

1. The [oEmbed](http://www.oembed.com/) functionality is applied in wordpress by a filter.
2. The [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function suppresses filters by default and I guess `get_post()` does the same, although I was not able to verify this in the documentation.

Perhaps you can use [query_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) (which doesn't suppress filters) or `get_posts()` with `suppress_filters=>false` to test this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I cannot make oEmbed works with get_posts() or query_posts(). However, I can make Smart Youtube plugin work with query_posts()